# Normal vector between two parallel lines

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Is there a way to calculate the normal vector of two parallel lines, without calculating the length or the points?

Comment: How are the lines specified?

Comment: in parametric form, in 3d space

Comment: What do you means by ''vertical vector''?

Comment: the perpendicular vector? sorry im not familiar with english math terms

Comment: @XBagon I would write instead, "the normal vector between the lines". (Strictly speaking, this is ambiguous, but this ambiguity amounts to a sign.)

Comment: This is very unclear: *"without calculating the length or the points"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the lines are those parallel to $\bf v$ and through the points ${\bf x}, {\bf y}$, so that the parameterizations are $t \mapsto {\bf x} + t {\bf v}$ and $t \mapsto {\bf y} + t {\bf v}$. Then, to recover the normal vector between the lines, we can simply project the difference ${\bf y} - {\bf x}$ onto the plane orthogonal to ${\bf v}$, giving the vector

$$({\bf y} - {\bf x}) - \operatorname{proj}_{\bf v}({\bf y} - {\bf x}) = ({\bf y} - {\bf x}) - \left(\frac{({\bf y} - {\bf x}) \cdot {\bf v}}{{\bf v} \cdot {\bf v}}\right) {\bf v} .$$

Of course, this formula simplifies nicely if we first normalize $\bf v$ to have unit length.

In $\Bbb R^3$, we can alternatively write this using the cross product. A quick geometric sketch shows that if we normalize $\bf v$ to produce a unit vector $\hat{\bf v}$, then the normal vector between the lines is
$$
\hat{\bf v} \times [({\bf y} - {\bf x}) \times \hat{\bf v}] .
$$

Comment: wow thanks man, I never would have thought of using the cross product twice.. but it makes sense. I just thought about using it once with both lines' v, but that's unfortunately zero, cause they're parallel.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful. You can actually pass back and forth between the two expressions (in the $3$-dim. case) using a so-called vector triple product identity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product